# MySQL: When are Referential Actions (ON DELETE; ON UPDATE) executed?

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints, innodb

I'm trying to act on a cascaded delete.

So if a row in parent Table "A" is deleted, all related child-rows in Table "B" should also be deleted AND when a row in "B" is deleted there should be an update on some other tables. (The constraints and ON DELETE CASCADE do work as expected.)

Because triggers aren't executed on referential actions, I tried to trigger the delete of the child-records. (`BEFORE DELETE ON 'A' ... DELETE FROM 'B' WHERE ...`) ... without success.

Why? And therefore: When are Referential Actions executed and is there a way to act before `ON DELETE`?

And: How is it possible to act on a cascaded or "trigger-triggered" UPDATE/DELETE.

I didn't find anything about that in the MySQL-Docs.

thx in advance

Comment: The real question is - what are you trying to do? What's the real problem behind this attempted solution of yours that doesn't work?

Comment: Sometimes FKs and Triggers are more trouble than simply doing the work the client code.

Comment: The real problem is, that I want to react on a cascaded delete.

Comment: Simplified: If a Row is deleted from "B", there should be a Log-Entry in Table "C". But "B" can be deleted directly or because of relations/constraints to Table "A".